# Pandas: transform rows into single column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I have the following pandas dataframe named `matches`:

```
id  |  name  |  age
1   |  a     |  19
1   |  b     |  25
2   |  c     |  19
2   |  d     |  22
```

I use a `groupby` + `count()`, if the value of a certain column (`age`) satisfies a condition (`x < 21`). The result is written into a new column (`new_col`):

```
matches['new_col'] = matches.groupby(['id'])['age'].transform(lambda x: x[x < 21].count())
```

The dataframe then looks like this:

```
id  |  name  |  age | new_col
1   |  a     |  19  | 1
1   |  b     |  25  | 1
2   |  c     |  19  | 2
2   |  d     |  18  | 2
```

Now I would like to output the result in a  more readable way, that is, the `name`-column of each row, where the condition (age < 21) is satisfied should be written into a new column, e.g., `result`.

I would expect something like this (however, there may be other ways to achieve this. maybe even do thi already in the first step, where I add `new_col`):

```
id  |  name  |  age | new_col | result
1   |  a     |  19  | 1       | a
1   |  b     |  25  | 1       | a
2   |  c     |  19  | 2       | c,d
2   |  d     |  18  | 2       | c,d
```

The last step (adding the `result` column) is where I am stuck right now.

Answer (score 2):

First filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html),  last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
matches1 = matches[matches.age < 21]
                          .groupby(['id'])['name'].agg({'result':', '.join, 'new_col': len})
print (matches1)
    new_col result
id                
1         1      a
2         2   c, d

print (matches.join(matches1, on='id'))
   id name  age  new_col result
0   1    a   19        1      a
1   1    b   25        1      a
2   2    c   19        2   c, d
3   2    d   18        2   c, d
```

Another solution with `double` `transform`, but first need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for next using [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) of values which are `>=21`:

```
matches = matches.sort_values(['id','age'])
g =  matches[matches.age < 21].groupby(['id'])['name']
matches['new_col'] = g.transform(len)
matches['result'] = g.transform(', '.join)
matches[['new_col','result']] = matches[['new_col','result']].ffill()

print (matches)
   id name  age  new_col result
0   1    a   19        1      a
1   1    b   25        1      a
3   2    d   18        2   d, c
2   2    c   19        2   d, c
```

Better explain necessary `sorting` a bit changed `df`:

```
print (matches)
   id name  age
0   1    a   25 > first value is filter out by condition
1   1    b   12
2   2    c   19
3   2    d   18

matches = matches.sort_values(['id','age'])
g =  matches[matches.age < 21].groupby(['id'])['name']
matches['new_col'] = g.transform(len)
matches['result'] = g.transform(', '.join)
matches[['new_col','result']] = matches[['new_col','result']].ffill()

print (matches)
  id name  age  new_col result
1   1    b   12        1      b
0   1    a   25        1      b
3   2    d   18        2   d, c
2   2    c   19        2   d, c

print (matches.sort_index())
   id name  age  new_col result
0   1    a   25        1      b
1   1    b   12        1      b
2   2    c   19        2   d, c
3   2    d   18        2   d, c
```

Answer (score 0):

I now made it like this: `groupBy` + `apply` + an apply function that adds the new column:

```
matches = matches.groupby(['id']).apply(concat)
```

concat is:

```
def concat(group):
    group['result'] = "{%s}" % ', '.join(group['name'][group['age'] < 21])
    return group
```

any other/better solutions?